# Why does Next.js display a <template data-dgst="NEXT_DYNAMIC_NO_SSR_CODE"> element instead of the component being rendered?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

The following React component

```
export default async function FooPage() {
  const { data } = await getServerData(); // a "use server" async function

  return <div>Foo</div>;
}
```

Produces the following initial HTML:

```html
<template data-dgst="NEXT_DYNAMIC_NO_SSR_CODE" data-msg="NEXT_DYNAMIC_NO_SSR_CODE">
</template>
```

When using SSR with Next.js, how can the component immediately render the HTML instead of a template tag?